# Safari App Extension is break point not work, not able to debug the code

Tags: xcode, safari-extension

I want to create a new Safari extension to get images. but as apple remove the facility Safari -> Develop ->  Show extension builder.
So, I am trying to create wit xCode -> macOS -> Safari App extension but I am unable how to debug the. Please guide me how I can debug my code.

Because button added in toolbar but nothing happen in code level.

Answer (score 4):

I got my breakpoint to work in Xcode by attaching to running extension process.  Look at your Xcode Menu->Debug->Attach to Process->{Your extension name}.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to debug my code with break points.
step share below (make sure you applied the break point in code)
1. Switch to the scheme for your extension and then Run.
2. Popup will ask you to choose an app from number of app, select Safari.